# How to enforce to https in Streamlit?

Tags: python, heroku, ssl-certificate, streamlit

Hi I have an application hosted with Heroku. I have a custom domain and I acquired an automated SSL certificate with Heroku. It works fine with no issue. My problem is that I would like to enforce the url to be always redirected to the https version. In other app's that I have done with Flask, I was able to enforce the https domain using Talisman. But this specific application was developed in Streamlit and therefore it is using a Tornado environment.

Specific example: when I type simply "my_webpage33.com" or "http://my_webpage33.com" it should go to "https://my_webpage33.com" so that no security warning message is displayed in the browser regarding the SSL certificate.

I asked the to Heroku support team but they replied that the issue falls outside the nature of the Heroku support policy.

Thanks!

Comment: That said, this is [documented](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/https-support) and, as I suspected, it should be done elsewhere like a reverse proxy. If heroku doesn't allow that configuration then you've still got the poor-man option

Comment: (And I don't think that documentation helps. Heroku is already handling the HTTPS connection as recommended there. The question is how to _force a redirect_ to HTTPS, which Heroku does _not_ do. They ask that [redirects be done at the application layer](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls).)

Comment: OP, did you write the code that spins up the Tornado server or is that hidden away behind Streamlit?

Comment: hi Chris I am not sorry about the answer to your question, I did not write anything for the tornado server. I simply deployed on Heroku and inserted "streamlit run application.py" in the procfile. And I agree that the documentation does not answer the question + please note that the SSL certificate is managed automatically by Heroku, I did not even have to manage any pem file.